# Git branch is entirely out of sync

Tags: git

My git environment is all mixed up!

I just pushed a commit to my 'python' branch. On my win 10 machine is where I pushed the files to git.

My win 10 machine shows this as the latest commit: `636b9de73fb1d79acaa4bb531f258103ece0ac4d`

The Bitbucket GUI (my company's git server) shows this as the latest commit for the python branch: `c1eaa115b71`

And if I do a `git pull origin python` on my Linux VM hosted in VMWare player, I show this as the latest commit:

```
 git log | head -10
commit 04dd8ca22fea0405db5dca8da43310223b72abce
Author: Tim  <tdunphY@company.com>
Date:   Fri Mar 15 07:00:06 2019 -0700

    Updated the source files for list instances.

commit 5d8738d75090a99c7c489cb8eb6b59fd57df7f56
Merge: 2c3970f 0b5a5bc
Author: Timothy P <tdunphy@company.com>
Date:   Thu Mar 14 09:33:52 2019 -0400
```

And if I try to check out what SHOULD be the latest commit on the Linux VM, I get an error:

```
git checkout 636b9de73fb1d79acaa4bb531f258103ece0ac4d
fatal: reference is not a tree: 636b9de73fb1d79acaa4bb531f258103ece0ac4d
```

I'm on git version 2.19.1.windows.1 on windows.

And I'm on git version 2.17.1 on Linux.

Just what in the heck is going on? And how do I correct that?

Comment: Did you push the commit from your windows machine to bitbucket, or did you just commit locally? It sounds like you only committed locally and haven't pushed it.

Comment: I pushed the commit from my windows machines with `git push origin python`

Comment: And did you pull on the other machine? And are they tracking the same repository and branch? The output of `git status` or `git log --oneline` might be helpful.

Comment: Yes I did a git pull on the other machine. And a git log does not show the commit that I'm missing. It's missing the one that I pushed from the windows machine.

Comment: Are you on the same branch? What does `git show-branch --more=5` return on each machine?

Comment: Yes I am on the same branch.

Comment: Run `git fetch` and then `git branch -vv` on your 2 machines and tell us what is the result.
Also, could it be one of then is a fork of the repository?